# PySide2 - Support Multi Language

Tags: multilingual, pyside2

How can I support multiple languages in the PySide2 app?

UI is generated by QT Designer.

Here is a simple application - https://github.com/openedhardware/SimpleMultiLangApp

This app has a combobox to switch the language and need to update all widgets correspondingly.

Thanks!

Comment: [Internationalization with Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html).

Comment: That is Qt document, not of pyside2... @ekhumoro